# Why my homestead always redirect to xampp homepage

Tags: laravel, redirect, xampp, homestead, hosts

I have a some question I'm so confused about this.
I've install `homestead` for Laravel 5 but I've some problem when I try to access my domain `laravel.dev` this will redirect to `xampp` home page. 
I was change `homestead.yaml` and `hosts` file but it doesn't work.

I was follow this instruction:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead
http://ambercat.rahmanda.net/collections/2015/02/18/instalasi-homestead.html

But is not help.

this is my Homestead.yaml

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: C:/xampp/htdocs
      to: /home/vagrant/Code
      type: "nfs"

sites:
    - map: laravel.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/laravel-crud/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

And this is my Hosts

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
192.168.10.10 laravel.dev
```

Can anyone help me for this problem?

Please advise
Thankyou..

Comment: If you enter `192.168.10.10` in a browser, do you see Laravel starting page?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin no, its same redirect to xampp homepage sir

Comment: You need to make `192.168.10.10` work first. Read installation manual one more time and check everything again. Also, update your post with your `homestead.yaml` please.

Comment: ok sir i was add, can you check what is wrong of my code

Comment: try to provision ur homestead, in case u modified homestead.yaml after ur homestead is running

Comment: @terrylow i was try and showing this "No input file specified." ?

Comment: do you have your project store here `C:/xampp/htdocs/laravel-crud` ? and also ensure you have index.php in `C:/xampp/htdocs/laravel-crud/public` please ensure your not testing it during provisioning process,

Comment: yes, if i access with this link http://localhost/laravel-crud/public/ its work fine

but if i access with laravel.dev will showing "No input file specified." after i run "vagrant provision"

Comment: ok then u have a change in .htaccess file, u try to comment out all ur .htaccess content and replace with `https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess`

Comment: yes i have, but its still not work sir

Comment: it is because you need to visit `laravel.dev` instead of `localhost/laravel-crud/public`, localhost/laravel-crud/public is where ur xampp handle the request